# Regex for names of sport teams

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm doing a sports-related quiz in JavaScript/jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/zVsxf/

I've cobbled some code together from answers on this site and it works fairly well but I have a small problem. I don't want the user to get credit for answering the Red Sox" and  the Red Wings as soon as s/he enters "Red". The same with "Blue" (Blues/Blue Jays/Blue Jackets) and "White" (White Sox).

I just need a regular expression, if it exists, or some advice on this part. Here's the most relevant code I have so far (in the jsFiddle link, it's on line 56:

```
if (current_name.match(RegExp('\\b' + entry + '\\b', 'i')))
```

Comment: It's not really clear what is your question…

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using regex at all?  Why not just require an exact match (maybe lower case both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per ernie's suggestion in the comments, ditch your regex and simply do an exact match like so:

Change

```
if (current_name.match(RegExp('\\b' + entry + '\\b', 'i')))
```

to:

```
if (current_name.toLowerCase() == entry.toLowerCase())
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/zVsxf/3/)
Use `toLowerCase()` to change both the correct answer and what the user submitted to all lower case so you don't have to worry about the difference between "Red Sox" and "red sox"

Comment: Since he's using jQuery, you might also throw a [trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) in there ;)

Comment: Thanks Dryden for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have above would return true if the team is "Red Sox" and they type "R". I think I would check if the team name has multiple words, and if so, a match would then be the first word instead of the entire team name.

Something like:

```
var match_compare;
var index = current_name.indexOf(' ');
if(index >= 0) {
    match_compare = current_name.substring(0, index);
}
else {
    match_compare = current_name;
}

// Then actually compare. I think they should be the exact same, just maybe 
// ignore case
if(match_compare.toLowerCase() == entry.toLowerCase()) {
    // Handle match
}
```